# Align text next to image when everything is wrapped in <p> tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I am pulling some markdown through an API (via contentful) and then using ReactMarkdown to convert it to html. The issue is that this then produces the following html

```
<p>Some text content</p>
<p>
  <img src="myImage.png" alt="my image">
</p>
<p>Multiple lines of text that I want to have next to the image</p>
```

I want to be able to put the "Multiple lines of text..." to the right of the image, as the image isn't the full width of the parent div. The problem is that the p tag the image is inside is filling the full width.

QUESTION: How can I place the text next to the image.

Things to note:

Depending on how the content is put into contentful it can be returned as:

```
<p>Some text content
  <img src="myImage.png" alt="my image">
Multiple lines of text that I want to have next to the image</p>
```

There may be other p tags inside the parent div either above or below "Some text..." or "Multiple lines of text..." depending on the content.

I have no ability to add class names to the different p tags

Comment: https://github.com/robert8888/remark-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a ReactMarkdown plugin -

```
<ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[gfm, remarkUnwrapImages]}>{markdownText1}</ReactMarkdown>
```

This allowed me to remove the p tags around the image. Thus I could then use css to wrap the p tags around the image